# Kepler.gl how to remove city/country names

Tags: python, data-visualization, kepler.gl

Using Kepler.gl data vizualisation. I want a clean dark map with only the datapoints. The names actually disturb in my case.

Is there a way to completely remove names?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Easy,

in the config dashboard there is a button to hide the layer.
You can find more [here](https://docs.kepler.gl/docs/user-guides/f-map-styles)